# how to save values of select options in javascript using e.target.value

Tags: javascript, dom

I gave some options some values in html and I want to save these values in a js var and I wrote the following  line but it didn't work

```
for (let node of document.getElementsByClassName('op.e.target.value')) {
values.push(node.value);
}
```

(where op is the class given to all the values)

Comment: if op is the class name what is .e.target.value? Is that other classes the elements also need to have to be selected?

Comment: var x = document.getElementsByClassName(***"Class Name"***);

Comment: .e.target is like a function that gets you all the information about the selected element which is the class op and adding .value gets you specifically the value of it

Comment: if I passed the class name it will return the text of the option and I want the value attribute @DomadiyaBhautik

Comment: The only time I've seen `e.target` is in relation to events, e.g. on click to get the clicked element. Anyway this wouldn't be where you'd use it

Comment: thanks for this little information I thought I can use it out of events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `getElementsByClassName` accepts class names as its argument only, not a function name in a string

When you're using `getElementsByClassName` you're storing an array of html elements, so to get the values of each you would need to for loop through it.

```js
var values1 = document.getElementsByClassName('op');

var values = [];
for (let node of values1) {
    values.push(node.value);
}
```